# i want to get value(amount) from webpage and verify that the value(amount) is equal or greater then $1000 in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, junit, automation

I want to get value(amount) from webpage and verify that the value(amount) is equal or greater than $1000 in selenium webdriver.

I have tried below code:-

```
WebElement CouponCodeAtCatalog = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='product-price-24276']/span"));
String CouponCodeAtCatalogPrint=CouponCodeAtCatalog.getText();

a = $1000;
String  b = ".//*[@id='product-price-24276']/span";
if (a > b) {
    //Below statement will be executed ONLY when 'a' is greater than b
    System.out.println("a is greater than b");
} else {
    //Below statement will be executed ONLY when 'b' is greater than 'a' or Equal to 'a'
    System.out.println("b is greater than a");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you :

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/");
WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.id("twotabsearchtextbox"));
webElement.sendKeys("seagate hard disk");
webElement.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
Thread.sleep(30000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("id('result_0')/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a")).click();
String price = driver.findElement(By.id("priceblock_ourprice")).getText();
int limit = 1000;
price = price.replace("$","");
int priceValue = Integer.parseInt(price.substring(0,price.indexOf(".")));
System.out.println("PriceValue : "+priceValue);
if( limit > priceValue)
    System.out.println("It is less than 1000");
else
    System.out.println("It is grater than 1000");
```

Modify this code for you requirement.

Comment: Yeah,,,, :) :) it's working for me, thank you so much